# How to place a "ribbon css" in particular <div> in order to achieve "Responsive"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I generated a CSS Ribbon for header. But when I try to use that code in bootstrap layout the ribbon header is not placed correctly. Below is my HTML Code.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ribbon">
                  <div class="ribbon-stitches-top">
                  </div>
                  <strong class="ribbon-content"><h1>Left Ribbon</h1></strong>
                  <div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ribbon-right">
                  <div class="ribbon-right-stitches-top">
                  </div>
                  <strong class="ribbon-right-content"><h1>Right Ribbon</h1></strong>
                  <div class="ribbon-right-stitches-bottom">
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <img alt="Image Preview" src="" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="disabled">
                    <a href="#">Messages</a>
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS Code:

```
 .ribbon {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  top: 4%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px!important;
  background: #b4bcde;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b4bcde),     to(#706bbd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b4bcde, #706bbd);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b4bcde, #706bbd);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b4bcde, #706bbd);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b4bcde, #706bbd);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b4bcde 0%, #706bbd 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
  box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .ribbon h1 {
  font-size: 24px!important;
  color: #fafafa;
  text-shadow: #98a7e3 0 1px 0;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  }

  .ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
  border-color: #677897 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: -1em;
  content: '';
  }
  .ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
  left: 0;
  border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
  }
 .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
  right: 0;
  border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
  }
 .ribbon-stitches-top {
  margin-top:2px;
  border-top: 0px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .ribbon-stitches-bottom {
  margin-bottom:2px;
  border-top: 0px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }

 /* ribbon-right */
 .ribbon-right {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 58.5%;
  top: 7%;
  z-index: -900;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px!important;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f7f7f7),  to(#9ab0d6));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #9ab0d6);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #9ab0d6);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #9ab0d6);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #9ab0d6);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7 0%, #9ab0d6 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
  box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
 .ribbon-right h1 {
  font-size: 22px!important;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: #a7b7b8 0 1px 0;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  }

 .ribbon-right .ribbon-right-content:after {
  border-color: #b8bfe0 transparent transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  bottom: -1em;
  content: '';
  }

  .ribbon-right .ribbon-right-content:after {
  right: 0;
  border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
  }
  .ribbon-right-stitches-top {
  margin-top:2px;
  border-top: 0px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
 .ribbon-right-stitches-bottom {
  margin-bottom:2px;
  border-top: 0px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 }
```

CSS code is bit large because I used ribbon CSS generator.

I tried removing position: absolute to position:relative. But it's not working.
How to put that ribbon in that `<div>` to fit correctly.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what's exactly you'd like to see and what's wrong in what you currently get

Comment: @Paradoxetion When I try to include the ribbon div into Bootstrap column div, the css of ribbon is changing. Ribbon design is not exactly when i generated it in ribbon generator.